# How to put a "carousel" div inside "oe_structure" without overlapping

Tags: css, layout, bootstrap-4, carousel, odoo-13

I need put a "carousel" div inside "oe_structure" but not work correctly, the "carousel" :

I'm editing the template "website_sale.products"

I am new to odoo, can I inherit in my direct code to edit the ? but I still don't know how to put the slider inside the div as shown in the image!

link of the code I use:

https://codeshare.io/2pBqez

My error with div carousel is:
[image]

Comment: Hi, can you share the CSS/JS other sheets too? I can'T reproduce your page just with the code you shared thank you

Comment: Hi @LaurentC, the technology is Odoo13! that inherit components, that is, I don't have the css or js!

Comment: I see. That is unfortunate. Well I'll give you a quick small demo and you can try to implement in your code? Otherwise I would need live access to your CMS to help more.

Comment: So if you can use/add custom code, you could add your carousel code and position it using one of the 3 methods I suggested let me know if you need + help

Comment: @LaurentC thxs. Sure we can create a live access! the problem is when I put the div with class: row o_wsale_products_main_row, if I mention that I am new to Odoo and I have been working to improve my ability in Python!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="square"><div>
    <div class="s-square">
</div>
```

```
.container {
  width:80%;background:lightgray;height:500px;margin-left:10%;
  display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;
} /* this container is positioned using a left-margin */

.square {width:250px;height:250px;background:white;position:relative;} /*this square is positioned by the flexbox display of its parent container (.container) */

.s-square {height:100px;width:100px;background:blue;position:absolute;top:50px;left:60px;3px dashed purple;} /* this is absolute positioning and should be avoided as much as possible b/c not very responsive-friendly */
```